# How to get input as a Left Arrow key?

Tags: python

I want to get the left and right arrow key as a one of the input.
How can i get it? Is there any way?

Comment: Please define "input", input on the console? On a window? If so which gui framework was used to created the window?

Comment: I want to get input on a window. It consists of some text field entries, if I press left arrow Key means the cursor have to move one field back. That is the thing I need. Well I have used GLADE (gtk-builder) and python to create the window.

Comment: terminal script -- I apologize for not clarifying earlier. My work never involves GUIs so it is not on my mind

Answer (score 6):

Using Tkinter you can do the following .... I found it on the net

```
# KeyLogger_tk2.py
# show a character key when pressed without using Enter key
# hide the Tkinter GUI window, only console shows

try:
   # Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    import tkinter as tk

def key(event):
"""shows key or tk code for the key"""
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
    if event.char == event.keysym:
     # normal number and letter characters
        print( 'Normal Key %r' % event.char )
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
      # charcters like []/.,><#$ also Return and ctrl/key
        print( 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char) )
    else:
      # f1 to f12, shift keys, caps lock, Home, End, Delete ...
        print( 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym )


root = tk.Tk()
print( "Press a key (Escape key to exit):" )
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
# don't show the tk window
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that is a substantial amount of complexity if the goal is a small, minimal script. Is there seriously no one/two line solution?

Answer (score 2):

That's how you can do it with ncurses. Unlike TkInter, X11 is not required.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import curses

screen = curses.initscr()
try:
    curses.noecho()
    curses.curs_set(0)
    screen.keypad(1)
    screen.addstr("Press a key")
    event = screen.getch()
finally:
    curses.endwin()

if event == curses.KEY_LEFT:
    print("Left Arrow Key pressed")
elif event == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
    print("Right Arrow Key pressed")
else:
    print(event)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with:

[Curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) [Urwid](http://excess.org/urwid/reference.html) [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/)

[Tkinter](http://docs.python.org/library/tkinter.html) is in the standard library.

Comment: Curses is also in the standard lib, isn't it?

Comment: @JFA: It isn't on Windows, but you can get it there.