# getKey from Ti-Basic in Python?

Tags: python, input, ti-basic

I was wondering how the getKey command works and how to use it in Python, as there is no command like that (right?).

Somehow, StackOverflow does not like short questions. I was writing a program on my calculator and then I thought, why not put it to my computer using Python? But then I realized I could not because I don't know what to do with the getKey.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your question, but this is the use of the getKey command in Ti-Basic:

```
:While 1         #loop
:Repeat X        #make sure a key is presssed
:getKey→X        #store that key in a variable
:End             #end loop
:Disp X
:End
```

getKey returns a value which corresponds to a key on the Ti-"Keyboard". You can look up the key values in the picture below.

[image: Ti-"keyboard"]

To get this functionality in Python search this site for it. You could use `.char` and `.keysym` for this. More info:

[Keypress detection Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204714/how-to-get-input-as-a-left-arrow-key)