# Why cant this code be repeated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I borrowed some code from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204714/how-to-get-input-as-a-left-arrow-key) I found on this website, but when I tried to form a program around it, I found that it can only be used once. Repeated code doesn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk

def keyDetect(event):
    root.destroy()
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        print(event.char)
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
        print(event.keysym, event.char)
    else:
        print(event.keysym)


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind_all('<Key>', keyDetect)
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()

print('1')
root = tk.Tk()
root.bind_all('<Key>', keyDetect)
print('2')
root.withdraw()
print('3')
root.mainloop()
print('4')
```

Using the 4 prints above shows where the problem is, `"3"` is printed but `"4"` isn't.

Comment: What's your actual goal here? That is, what are you trying to achieve by the duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`Tk.mainloop()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.mainloop-method) starts Tkinter's main event loop.  This is an infinite loop that will continue until the main window is destroyed (closed).  So, your program will not execute any lines following `root.mainloop()` until the loop exits.

An analogy would be:

```
print('3')
while True:
    pass
print('4')
```

Note however that Tkinter's loop is doing a lot more than just `pass`ing.  It is handling events, keeping the main window open, etc.

Comment: Yes, the loop will be exited by destroying the main window.  This can be accomplished by doing `root.quit()`.

Comment: I added `root.quit()` after `root.mainloop()` but nothing changed. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, not exactly.  Like I said in my answer, the lines after `root.mainloop()` will not be executed until the loop exits. In order to do what you want, you would need to hook `root.quit` up to a button or do `root.after(1, root.quit)` just before you call `root.mainloop()`.  But I don't know why you are destroying the window just after you create it.  If you don't need the window just yet, then simply don't call `root.mainloop()` until you are ready for it.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Well how would you use tkinter (or anything else) to detect keystrokes in more than one place?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.  If you need multiple windows, you can use the [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) class to create children windows.  Or, if you need multiple instances of your program, you can have another Python script launch them in a loop.  If you are trying to build a global keyboard hook however, that is a lot more involved.  You can find some info [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) and you may want to check out [pyHook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook).

Comment: What about `root.destroy()` in there? It's not infinite then

Comment: @Defalt - `root.destroy()` never gets executed because the OP is calling `root.withdraw()`.  This hides the main window, so it will never receive any key press events.  If the `root.withdraw()` lines are removed, the program will no longer run continuously because you can destroy the windows by clicking a key when they have focus.